# What does access$ mean in an android studio project?

Tags: android-studio

I really do not understand that, I'm a beginner in programming.

For example:

```
StartActivity.access$202(StartActivity.this, 0);
```

or

```
StartActivity.a|ccess$402(StartActivity.this, true ^ StartActivity.this.gl_bShowConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$` character is used in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

See Java specs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8